# How can I determine how much memory my java program is consuming

Tags: java

I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  //I want statistics here
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try use [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) it comes bunddled with JDK/J2SE

Comment: Can you post some code.

Comment: are you talking about memory taken by an object?

Comment: No the total available and used memory of JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();

sb.append("free memory: " + format.format(freeMemory / 1024) + "<br/>");
sb.append("allocated memory: " + format.format(allocatedMemory / 1024) + "<br/>");
sb.append("max memory: " + format.format(maxMemory / 1024) + "<br/>");
sb.append("total free memory: " + format.format((freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory)) / 1024) + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) has all the memory data available. This includes data about both heap and non heap memory. The `Runtime` class only provides access to information about heap memory.